# How to decode gzip STRING?

Tags: python, gzip, decode

I've handling the SMTP server input emails log with my unittest and have the gzip data in email attachment. As i need to exclude unnecessary data from log i open the file with r mode. In the result i have the next STRING for attached data to email

```
b'H4sIAPjl018C/wvJyCxWAKKUxJJEhbT8IoWCxKKSzJLM/DwFQwB9NabZHAAAAA=='
```

the type -- string!

Do the exist way to decode in python this STRING from gzip to simple string representation?
the decode should be

```
This is data for partition 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the data you're working with is actually [base64-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) after being compressed with gzip, so it's necessary to reverse both the encoding and the compression to get back the original content. You can use the `base64` and `gzip` libraries, like so:

```py
import base64
import gzip

encoded = ... # Get the encoded data somehow
compressed = base64.b64decode(encoded)
original = gzip.decompress(compressed)
print(original) # b'This is the data for partition 1'
```

Comment: can i place the string b'H4sIAPjl018C/wvJyCxWAKKUxJJEhbT8IoWCxKKSzJLM/DwFQwB9NabZHAAAAA==' as not a string to base64.b64decode(PLACE WHERE I WANNA)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm sorry. If you mean there could be issues because it's bytes, don't worry, it works fine